# Will using a master login username and password when implementing web services considered secure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, security

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application and I have started implementing some web services which provides statistical information about my site. But to make sure that only authorized and authenticated consumers can call and consume the web services I am thinking of defining a master login username and password for each consumer, and when a consumer sends a web service request he should include these master login username and password (stored as a hash value ) in the web service calls.

For example the web service link to call specific web service from my web site will look as follow:-

```
/web/json/statistic/getsummaryinfo/areacode?j_username=masterusername&hash=D012B772672A55A0B561EAA53CA7734E
```

**So my question is whether the approach I am following will provide a secure solution to my web services and to the consumers? OR my approach have security holes I am unaware of ?**

**:::EDITED::**

I am using the WebAPI controllers to implement the web services inside my asp.net mvc-4.**

Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to make sure things are secure.

1. http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/08/soa-softwares-api-management-platform-and-how-it-compares-to-its-sexy-counterparts/ This article just came out today highlighting some API tools.  I'm not sure how big you are or are planning to be, but if you're looking for scale, these tools seem to be pretty popular (note: I haven't had a large scale API project myself, so I haven't used these).
2. You can use something like ServiceStack to build your API layer.  It has authorization and authentication built in with a boatload of authentication providers.  It scales well and, after a call to authenticate, is session-based so you don't have to authenticate each call.
3. You can use "signed" requests. Signed requests often look something like: "take all the parameters for the request as a querystring, append a 'secret consumer key' to the end of the request', and then sign the request by appending the md5 hash of the results **(without the secret key!!)** to the request."  This is a safe way of doing things because even if the request is made client-side (AJAX) it is generated server-side using a secret key.  So you can ensure that things weren't tampered with.
4. You can go the oauth/token route (which often still uses method #3 above).
5. You can go with a simple API key that can be revoked (again, fotne used with method #3).  bit.ly uses this method I think.

Option #2 is my favorite.  I like ServiceStack.  But to be honest the learning curve for your first project can be a little steep.

A master username and hashed password feels weak to me, so I'd strongly consider at least looking around at how others are doing it.

HTH

Comment: thanks for the reply, just to add to my original question ; i do not need another tool to build the web services as i am using the webapi controllers to implement the web services inside my asp.net ,vc-4 web application.

Answer (score 0):

I do not consider your way to be safe. If I could listen on the wire and cache the request I will have the login an the password to the service. There even does not matter if the password is hashed or not. I like the point 3. in Eli Gassert's answer. It sounds very useful and light weight and you are not exposing the password because it is hashed "somewhere" in the request.

Comment: but what if i use https then will my approahc be secure ?.

Comment: Only from outsiders peeking at your data while it's traveling over the wire.  If anyone "sees" the request (pre-transfer) of anyone else, it's going to be very easy to impersonate that user.  Are these requests always server-to-server and never anything even remotely client facing?  What's the difference between them using their own username and password, vs this "master" username/password you're proposing?

Comment: @Eli Gasset. You mentioned "What's the difference between them using their own username and password, vs this "master" username/password you're proposing?". The difference is that my asp.net is offering web services to other application so i am unaware of their usernames and passwords, so i set the master login username and password so that it will be send with each web service request .